# Ruby on rails and composition in OOP: How can I access attributes in simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop

I am making a form for sign up and I have a class named ManagedCompany, that have an attribute named company of the class Company. The class Company have an attribute from another class named Address. So, there are compositions in those classes.

The classes are presented below:

**app/models/managed_company.rb**

```
class ManagedCompany
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def initialize
    @company = Company.new
  end

  attr_accessor :name, :string
  attr_accessor :company, :Company

end
```

**app/models/company.rb**

```
class Company
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def initialize
    @address = Address.new
  end

  attr_accessor :category, :string
  attr_accessor :name, :string
  attr_accessor :address, :Address

  validates_presence_of :category
  validates_presence_of :name

end
```

**app/models/address.rb**

```
class Address
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :street, :string
  attr_accessor :number, :string

  validates_presence_of :street
  validates_presence_of :number

end
```

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @managed_company do |form| %>

  <%= form.input :company.address.street, autofocus: true %>

<% end %>
```

But this way did not work. The error message:

```
undefined method `address' for :company:Symbol
```

So, in the form (simple_form of ruby on rails), how can I access the attribute street from the address object?

**Edit: add controllers code**

**app/controllers/managed_companies_controller.rb**

```
class ManagedCompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @managed_companies = ManagedCompanies.new
  end

  def create
    @managed_companies = ManagedCompanies.new(secure_params)
    if @managed_companies.valid?

    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:managed_companies).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

**app/controllers/companies_controller.rb**

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @company = Company.new
  end

  def create
    @company = Company.new(secure_params)
    if @company.valid?

    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

**app/controllers/addresses_controller.rb**

```
class AddressesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @address = Address.new
  end

  def create
    @address = Address.new(secure_params)
    if @address.valid?

    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

  def secure_params
    params.require(:address).permit(:street)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%= form.input @company.address.street, autofocus: true %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I got this error now: `undefined method 'address' for nil:NilClass`. Seems that my object company is null. Do you know how to instantiate the variable? Because I dont want to save the form data on database. I just want populate the model and send to a remote Web Service. I try to instantiate these nil variable on the form, with `<%= @company = Company.new %>`  and `<%= @company.address = Address.new%>`, but I got `undefined method humanize' for nil:NilClass`. Can you help me?

Comment: Take a look at your app/models/address.rb class name: "class Endereco" should be "class Address", shouldn't it?
If that doesn't do the trick, update your post with the recent code and include the controller code. thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm making refactoring the code and rewriting all classes and methods. Now I can't update the code because I'am at work. As soon as possible I will update it.

Comment: The code is up to date and with the controllers now. Thank you for spend your time for helping me.

Comment: I believe I have found the solution. Basically I made a loop for each attribute of the classes that were attributes of another. I will finish the code and post here if I find a solution. I switch to bootstrap_form_for too. But the example: `<%= bootstrap_form_for @managed_companies do |form| %>
  <%= bootstrap_form_for @managed_companies.company.address do |form| %>
    <%= form.text_field :street, autofocus: true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>`. I did not test the code when submit is clicked, but the form is shown now. Tomorrow I will work more in this problem.